# Count characters between specific tags/words

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

I have an excel file whose strings can't be longer than 60 characters. Some strings are limited by `<br>` and some others use `<break>`. So for example, I have this cell:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam amet.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor 
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu sed.<break>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
```

I want excel or Notepad++ to highlight strings between tags that are longer than 60 character, is there any "easy" way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged it with **regex** and **excel**, here is a VBA macro using regular expressions to highlight long phrases in a cell.  I assumed your example above was all in one cell.  Each substring of more than 60 characters will highlight (alternately) in red or green.  The macro runs on the cell(s) you **select**.  It could be modified to run on other ranges.

**EDIT** *Code changed to only highlight the portion of the strings between tags.  Before it was highlighting the starting tag also*

```
Option Explicit
Sub HiglightGT60()
    Dim S As String
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const MaxLen As Long = 60
    Dim bColorFlag As Boolean

Set R = Selection
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(^|<br>|<break>)((?!<br>|<break>)[\s\S]){" & MaxLen + 1 & ",}"
        .MultiLine = False
    End With

For Each C In R
    C.Font.Color = vbBlack
    S = C.Text
    If RE.test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(S)
        For Each M In MC
            C.Characters(M.firstindex + 1 + Len(M.submatches(0)), _
                            M.Length - Len(M.submatches(0))) _
                            .Font.Color = IIf(bColorFlag, vbRed, vbGreen)
            bColorFlag = Not bColorFlag
        Next M
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

I don't know about **Notepad++** but I imagine the regex would be similar

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you may try this little VBA code:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim search_area As String
search_area = "B3:B8"
Dim separator As String
separator = "<br>"
Dim lengthLimit As Long
lengthLimit = 60

Dim text As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim row As Long

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.range(search_area).Cells
    row = cell.row
    col = cell.Column + 1
    text = Split(cell, separator, -1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(text)
        If (Len(text(i)) > lengthLimit) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = text(i)
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub

See this recording on how it can be integrated with Excel
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/ymse6uo5hhtvqry/vba.gif

- You press Alt+F11 to enter into VBA mode.
- Then insert a UserForm and add a button.
- Double click on the button and paste above code.
- Now, press the Play button. Click on the button.

Assuming the long text are in B3:B8 range, if there are longer than 60 chars within 
 tag, that piece of text will be shown in the columns next to column B.

Answer (score 0):

**For Notepad++** I'm afraid I can't see a way to negate a combination of symbols. You can't use:

```
^(<br>|<break>)
```

So the next best thing I can think of is to do something like this:

```
.{60}(<br>|<break>)
```

However this will only highlight the line if it eventually ends with a br/break, but has 60 other characters on it before the break. If there is no break at the end the line would not get highlighted.

You could possibly check for \n as well if this is good enough:

```
.{60}(<br>|<break>|\n)
```

To highlight just hit Ctrl+F, switch to the Mark tab, set the search mode to Regex and hit Mark All (Don't forget to clear previous markings)

This is the best option I can think of with Notepad++, and it requires very little effort.